# Connecting Cloud SQL to BigQuery (Error: Method not found)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I tried connecting my Cloud SQL instance using graphical interface and receive an error:[image]

Apart from trying graphical interface, I tried to connect it via shell:

```
bq mk --connection --connection_type='CLOUD_SQL' --properties='{"instanceId":"federation-test:us-central1:mytestsql","database":"mydatabase","type":"MYSQL"}' --connection_credential='{"username":"myusername", "password":"mypassword"}' --project_id=federation-test --location=us my_new_connection
```

but received the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u201d' in position 250: ordinal not in range(256)
```

I tried fixing it by trying the following route:

> Choose Cloud SQL instance -> Edit -> Flag -> character_set_server [utf8] -> Save

[image]

But even after doing it "UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1'" error stayed.

Can someone help to connect Cloud SQL instance to my BQ. Im new to cloud computing, so don't know much yet.

Instance info:

1. Location: europe-west4
2. Database version: MySQL 5.7

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: There is a [similar issue reported in the public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/166578431). Could you try running the command on a Compute Engine VM and let us know about the result?

Comment: @Katayoon thank you for the help. I just run exactly the same command as before but in Compute Engine VM, however it still doesn't work and shows different error. Attached error screenshot after EDIT

Comment: As the error message denotes, it is recommended to create a report in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659) so that we would be able to look into the issue.